# Swift - Simple fix for "Instance member cannot be used on type" error?

Tags: json, swift, parsing, boolean, decoding

Here is the JSON "decoding"/parsing I did based on the [isSteamDown JSON](https://issteamdown.com/status.json) page:

```
struct Instruction: Decodable {
    let statuses: [Status]
    let message, messageURL: String
    let status: Bool
    let load, time: Int

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case statuses, message
        case messageURL = "message_url"
        case status, load, time
    }
}
```

And here is the code I wrote to try and decode it:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        let url = "https://issteamdown.com/status.json"
        let urlObj = URL(string: url)

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlObj!) {(data, response, error) in

            do {
                guard let json = (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers)) as? [String: Any] else {
                        return
                    }
                for statusCheck in json {
                    print(Instruction.status)
                }
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

The error I am having is with the print line here:

```
for statusCheck in json {
    print(Instruction.status)
}
```

and the error is as follows:

> Instance member 'status' cannot be used on type 'Instruction'

What I am wondering is: What is the solution to this specific issue with *my* code?

Also: Is there a general solution for this that usually works for this error format?

Also if it is not too much to ask, could you please explain the reasoning behind your answer in as layman of terms as possible?

---

**EDIT**: I tried changing "Instruction.status" to "statusCheck.status" and it returned the error:

> Value of tuple type '(key: String, value: Any)' has no member 'status'

Comment: What is `Status`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Status should adapt Decodable also..
And you should use JSONDecodable method like below.

```
struct Status: Decodable {
    let title: String
    let code: Int
    let status: Bool
    let time: Int
}

struct Instruction: Decodable {
    let statuses: [Status]
    let message, messageURL: String
    let load: Int

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case statuses, message
        case messageURL = "message_url"
        case load
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        let url = "https://issteamdown.com/status.json"
        let urlObj = URL(string: url)

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlObj!) {(data, response, error) in
            guard let data = data else { return }
            do {
                let json = try JSONDecoder().decode(Instruction.self, from: data)
                json.statuses.forEach { status in
                    print(status)
                }
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }

            }.resume()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use `JSONDecoder` as opposed to `JSONSerialization` for `Decodable` types.

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
guard let instruction = try decoder.decode(Instruction.self, from: data!) else { return }
print(instruction.status) // no need for 'for' loop!
```

Here is the above code in context of your existing code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        let url = "https://issteamdown.com/status.json"
        let urlObj = URL(string: url)

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlObj!) {(data, response, error) in

            do {
                // write the above code here
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

Comment: Pardon my ignorance but where in the code should I put that? I'm guessing that I can replace the guard I have right now with the guard you provided but does it matter where I put the "let decoder" line? This sounds promising as I do remember a guide to decoding I saw used something named JSONDecoder but do I have to import anything?

Comment: @bluewizard3 See the edit. You don't need to import anything. I think it is in the `Swift` module, which is implicitly imported.

Comment: @bluewizard3 Also, remember to make `Status` conform to `Codable` as well, if you haven't already.

Comment: Do you mean conform to Decodable?

Comment: @bluewizard3 Yes, but it doesn't really matter. Did my answer work for you?

Comment: Sadly no, I now have an error on the second to last closing bracket of the document saying expected declaration (I have the same amount of open/closed curly brackets and parentheses) and one on the URLSession.shared.dataTask line that says: "Invalid conversion from throwing function of type '(_, _, _) throws -> ()' to"

Comment: can we move this to somewhere else in order to "avoid extended discussions in comments"? Perhaps reddit PM or something?